# Redirect all request to 403 forbidden except few files and folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `.htaccess` file as below,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /posnicpro/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?api/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ api.php?controller=$1&action=$2&eparam=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !dashboard.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/assets/)
RewriteRule . - [L,F]
```

Its working up to first rule (`^/?api/...`)

But second rule is not working (`RewriteRule . - [L,F]`).

I want achieve, all request should throw 403 (forbidden) except `index.php, dashboard.php` and `assets` folder.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Try removing the first two conditions from your second rule block `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` and 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` .

Comment: you are right @starkeen working expected ! your comment should be in the answer section :)